# What does the Shield over a city mean?

Tags: shadow-kings

When I go into the world map I notice other player's cities have a shield (kinda like a force field) around them and some don't. What exactly is this shield?

Answer (score 1):

This is like the equivalent to a Shield in Clash of Clans called a force-field, as in the diamond store you can buy varying lengths of them (the maximum being 60 days).

**Benefits**

- Your castle and outposts can not be attacked
- Your castle is protected from "ruin" during that time

**Disadvantages**

- Troop Training is slowed down